# Agregar transición a la aparición de un DIV

Tags: html5, css3, formularios

Tengo un `div` en el formulario de contacto que está oculto, y cuando el mail se manda exitosamente, este `div` aparece con un mensaje. Lo que estoy intentando hacer es agregarle una transición, como por ejemplo, que aparezca con un `fade`, o que se abra desde arriba, y no de golpe.

He intentado poniendo `transition: opacity 2s linear;` a la clase del `div`, pero no funciona.

No se qué propiedad debo poner y en dónde.

Dejo mi código aquí:

```js
success :  function(enviado){ 
    console.log(enviado);
    if (enviado == 1){
        $("#divmensaje").removeClass("oculto");
        $("#divmensaje").addClass("visible");
        borrarCampos();
    }
}
};
```

```css
.correct {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: mediumseagreen;
  border-color: mediumseagreen;
  border: 1px solid; 
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  padding-top: 15px;   
}      
    
.oculto{
  display: none;
}

.visible{
  display: inherit;
  transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<!-- el botón del formulario que envía el mail -->
<input type="button" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary submit" name="submit" id="enviar"/>

<!-- el div que aparece cuando se manda exitosamente el mail -->
<div id="divmensaje" class="status oculto correct">¡Tu mensaje ha sido enviado con éxito!</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En **CSS** la propiedad `display` no se puede animar en ninguno de sus valores, es por eso que debes cambiar `display: none` y `display: block` por `visibility: hidden` y `visibility: visible` respectivamente, una vez hecho esto la animación del `opacity` funcionará correctamente.

**EDICIÓN:**  para que el espacio blanco del `div` no se viera reflejado entonces se deben colocar en valor `0` las márgenes (internas y externas) y el `height` del `div`, y luego restablecerlo a los valores que tenias predeterminados, incluso una vez hecho esto ni siquiera necesitarías agregar la propiedad `visibility`

```js
$("#enviar").click(function(){
  $("#divmensaje").removeClass("oculto");  
  $("#divmensaje").addClass("visible");
})
```

```css
.correct {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: mediumseagreen;
  border-color: mediumseagreen;
  border: 1px solid; 
}      
    
.oculto{
   visibility: hidden; /* Al alterar las márgenes y el height no es necesaria esta propiedad */
   opacity: 0;
   height: 0;
   padding: 0;
}

.visible{
    visibility: visible; /* Al alterar las márgenes y el height no es necesaria esta propiedad */
    opacity: 1;
    height: auto;
    padding: 15px 0px;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- el botón del formulario que envía el mail -->
<input type="button" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-primary submit" name="submit" id="enviar"/>

<!-- el div que aparece cuando se manda exitosamente el mail -->
<div id="divmensaje" class="status oculto correct">¡Tu mensaje ha sido enviado con éxito!</div>
```

Comment: Hola! Realmente me ha funcionado. Pero el espacio en blanco en donde iría el div puede verse en la web. Hay alguna manera de que eso no ocurra? Yo por eso había elegido usar `display: none`

Comment: @CarlaPaludetto te acabo de editar la respuesta, saludos

Comment: Vi la edición. Muchísimas gracias, me ha funcionado perfectamente!

Answer (score -1):

Intenta con esto:

```
.correct {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: mediumseagreen;
    border-color: mediumseagreen;
    border: 1px solid; 
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    padding-top: 15px;  
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 2s linear;
}      


.visible{
    opacity:1;
}
```

```
success: function(enviado){ 
    if (enviado == 1){
        $("#divmensaje").addClass("visible");
        borrarCampos();
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor considera agregar una explicación a tu código, para que la comunidad sepa que modificaste y como esto soluciona el problema, lee [answer]